# How to aggregate total amount of precipitation from all cells within three seperate catchments?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, aggregation, inverse-distance-weighted, precipitation

Using ArcGIS Pro, I ran 4 different IDW interpolations (rasters) of rainfall measurements across 26 measurement stations (point features). I'm trying to now aggregate the total amount of precipitation within 3 different river catchment areas (polygon features), but cannot find a way to clip and total the aggregate raster results.

How can I calculate the total amount of precipitation within each polygon feature?

Here is a screenshot of an aggregate sum of one IDW interpolation and the 3 river catchment areas:
[image]

Comment: Try zonal statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is a solution that might fit your problem (check TimothyHales answer): https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-spatial-analyst-questions/sum-of-all-pixel-cell-values-of-a-raster-map/td-p/230170